# GDAL API tutorial does not link: As if CreateLayer is not a member of GDALDataset: Why?

Tags: gdal

Code: taken from tutorial - plus some include files:

```
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h" // for CPLMalloc()
#include "ogrsf_frmts.h"
int main()
{
        GDALDataset *poDS;
        OGRLayer *poLayer;
        char     **papszOptions;
        papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue( papszOptions, "DIM", "2" );
        poLayer = poDS->CreateLayer( "NewLayer", NULL, wkbUnknown,
                                     papszOptions );
}

Build command:
g++ -ggdb -Wall -std=c++0x -o  $1 $1.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lgdal -L/usr/lib64 -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/local/include/
```

Message from compiler.

```
CreateLyr.cpp: In function int main()\u2019:
CreateLyr.cpp:10:25: error: class GDALDataset\u2019 has no member named CreateLayer
         poLayer = poDS->CreateLayer( "NewLayer", NULL, wkbUnknown,
```

How to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using GDAL/OGR 1.11 and reading the API tutorial for the latest (2.x) version. The API changed quite a bit between 1.x and 2.x. The OGR API tutorial for GDAL 1.11 is http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/ogr_apitut.html

Comment: It turns out that my link was bad. We had to do an export:a. $export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/my-directory/conda/lib in order to link with the version 2.4 that I'd built locally. Even though ogrinfo found GPKG in my local version my link was bypassing to the older system version. Modifying the Make and defining the LD Path with the export command solved above solved the problem and I am able to access the C++ driver.